# How to apply default post categories to link manager plugin

Tags: links

I have a project with several custom post types - all sharing the default WP post category taxonomy.

I would like to add the [link manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/link-manager/) (Formally built into WP pre 3.5) to manage links - also sharing the default WP post categories. By default, though, the plugin needs you to create separate (link specific) categories.

Does anyone know of a simple way to get it to sync with the default wp categories. Something in the functions file.

Ta.
P.

Comment: Could you elaborate at which plugin and how you are using? I don't quite follow what are your "sync" challenges.

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. By 'link manager plugin' I mean this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/link-manager/ (the one that was formally built into Wordpress prior to 3.5).